# How can I use jsonAssertion.softAssert to assert that an element is visible

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm using softAssertions in my Cypress test. I was able to use the **softAssert()** method to verify the text in an element, but I'm trying to figure out how to use the **softAssert()** method to assert that an element is visible. In cypress it is simple I use **.should('be.visible')** but I can't seem to make it work with the **softAssert()** method. The elements that I am trying to assert are input fields,tables and buttons. I gave a simple example below.

Thats how I did it:

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

Cypress.Commands.add('softAssert', (actual, expected, message) => {
  jsonAssertion.softAssert(actual, expected, message)
  if (jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.length) {
    jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.forEach(diff => {

      const log = Cypress.log({
        name: 'Soft assertion error',
        displayName: 'softAssert',
        message: diff.error.message
      })
    
    })
  }
});

Cypress.Commands.add('softContains', (actual, expected, message) => {
  jsonAssertion.softContains(actual, expected, message)
  if (jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.length) {
    jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray.forEach(diff => {

      const log = Cypress.log({
        name: 'Soft assertion error',
        displayName: 'softContains',
        message: diff.error.message
      })
    
    })
  }
});

  Cypress.Commands.add('softAssertAll', () => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll())
```

This is mine custom commands and this is the actual test

```js
describe('Load Validation Test', function(){
    const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")
  
    it('Load Validation Test', function(){ 
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('div table[class="table table-striped b-t b-light table-nowrap"]').should('be.visible')

    })
  })
```

Answer (score 5):

For any criteria not supported out of the box, use a general `.then()` callback to apply `jsonAssertion.softAssert()`.

```js
const jsonAssertion = require("soft-assert")

it('Load Validation Test', function() { 
  cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]')
    .then($input => {
      const isVisible = $input.is(':visible')
      jsonAssertion.softAssert(isVisible, true, 'should be visible')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

It is doable, but you need a wrapper to extract the `actual` and `expected` values

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('softVisible', {prevSubject:true}, 
  (subject, expectedCondition, message) => {

    // translate expectedCondition to true/false
    const expected = expectedCondition === 'be.visible'
  
    // get actual from subject
    const actual = subject.is(":visible")

    cy.softAssert(actual, expected, message)
})

// usage
cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').softVisible('be.visible')
cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').softVisible('not.be.visible')
```

Be careful about using `softVisible`, if you want to control test flow

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]')
  .softVisible('be.visible')
  .type('my activity')
```

This will not wait for visibility before running `.type()`.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in the [soft-assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-assert) npm library, they support all the below methods and I cannot see a method for checking `visibility`.

```js
1.  deepAssert(actual, expected, msg, ignoreKeys)
2.  softAssert(actual, expected, msg, ignoreKeys)
3.  deepContains(actual, expected, msg, ignoreKeys)
4.  softContains(actual, expected, msg, ignoreKeys)
5.  deepAssertKey(actual, expected, key, msg, ignoreKeys)
6.  softAssertKey(actual, expected, key, msg, ignoreKeys)
7.  deepContainstKey(actual, expected, key, msg, ignoreKeys)
8.  softContainsKey(actual, expected, key, msg, ignoreKeys)
9.  deeptTrue(value, msg)
10. softTrue(value, msg)
11. deepAssertKeyAbsence(actual, key, msg)
12. softAssertKeyAbsence(actual, key, msg)
13. softAssertAll()
```

Alternatively, if you just want to test whether the element is visible or not and do some actions without failing the test you can:

```js
describe('Load Validation Test', function () {
  it('Load Validation Test', function () {
    if (Cypress.$('input[placeholder="Activity Name"]').is(':visible')) {
      //Element is visible, do something
    } else {
      //Element is not visible, do something
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your two methods softAssert and softAssertAll, you just need to add one more, to verify when one element is present or not. Like this.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isTheElementPresent', (ele) => {
    cy.get('body').then($body => {
        if ($body.find(ele).length) return true
        else return false
    });
})
```

Then, in your test you can combine those methods in this way:

```
cy.isTheElementPresent('.site-description').then(isTrue => {
  cy.softAssert(isTrue, true, "expected this element to be present!");
})

// Here we can put extra assertions or any other additional code...

// Finally:
cy.softAssertAll();
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do it, Cypress tells us the web page is unstable and adds retry to `$body.find(el)` - but you are bypassing the built-in retry.

Comment: Also, you are testing `existence` not `visibility`.

Comment: You're right. Actually I realized that it's possible to do it even by just using only the first softAssert method in the original question. For exaple:

cy.get('table').contains('td', 'Norma')
                .then(el => {
                    cy.softAssert(el.is(":visible"), true, "expected this element to be visible!");
                })